# Forcing Google DNS manually on Linux skipping local DNS

Tags: linux, dns

I am having trouble with DNS on Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian and using a 4G-dongle (ZTE MF823).

I had problems from the beginning when my program was posting to a website I got an automatic 200 OK respons but there was no data sent.

I found the problem to be the DNS adress that the USB 4G-dongle gave the raspberry pi. Once I changed to Googles DNS in resolv.conf it started working again. 
So I figured that I only use Google DNS and not bother.
But at reboot and sometimes when the 4G-dongle changes network to 3G the old local DNS is written back into resolv.conf. I am guessing the 4G-dongle is sending the data to Linux and linux puts it on top of the file automatically.

I have found a lot of information about resolv.conf and DNS on the internet but I have not found any information on how I can force Linux to only and in all cases use Googel DNS 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

What I have tried:

- I have set up Google DNS in interfaces anlong with static ip and
  everything. The google DNS shows up in resolv.conf but under the local DNS.
- Installed the full resolvconf on raspbian since that is
  not installed from the beginning.
- Found a file that orders the interfaces and added usb0 over all other.

So does anyone have any idea about this?

My other possible solution is to telnet into the usb modem since it is running linux and mess around in it and try to get the DNS working properly but I rather just set up the raspberry and not be dependent on the modem. And I will have to do this on all my modems. But if I have it on my rasbian image i can copy the solution to all raspberries. I might have 30 units running if we can get approval of the pilot.

Comment: I had a related problem.
Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40339007/6102357.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to write a script and have it execute upon startup. Not elegant but it might work it would look something like

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script to set DNS to Google DNS Servers
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8 \n nameserver 8.8.4.4" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then save that file and add the following to the appropriate rcX.d where X is your runlevel.

```
ln -s /path/to/script SXX.setGoogleDNS
```

Where XX is the order in which you'd want it to start at. My suggestion would be the high 90's so that you can ensure it runs after the rest of the network config occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution that solves the problem.

It seem like on the raspberry pi the dhcp client still runs even if you have stated static IP. (somehow).

To make the local DNS in resolv.conf go away i just uninstalled the dhcp-client.

```
sudo apt-get remove dhcpcd5
```

Not really sure why this was needed but as I am setting up an static IP i don't really need the dhcp-client.