# How to set DNS servers manually?

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi, raspbian

How do I exclude DNS from the DHCP lease request on a Raspberry Pi?

I tried updating `/etc/resolv.conf` but it's reset after a while.

Reason: I am on a home network, and the home router uses itself as the DNS server, but the router's DNS service isn't working properly sometimes.

Answer (score 9):

Most of the answers didn't work for me, but I found that this worked:

`sudo vi /etc/dhcpcd.conf`

Added a line (note that there is no comma):

`static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

And unplugged and replugged my ethernet cable, which updates the resolver...

`cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Now shows:

```
# Generated by resolvconf
domain example.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

This also a better way to fix the problem where changes to `/etc/resolv.conf` are lost on reboot.

Answer (score 3):

I asume the problem is, that the dhcpclient is getting new information about DNS servers with every dhcp-renewal. Add this line into /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf:

```
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.8, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
```

Of course you should replace the ip-addresses with the ones from your demanded DNS server. Probably restart the according service.